# Does web explorers have an id or something like that?

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I wonder if the explorers has a unique id or something because I’m making an experiment and I realized that Google detect it’s the same computer even if I chance many things.
I have tried all

- I have install and uninstall chrome
- Change local ip
- Change external ip
- Change the mac network
- Change the mac router
- Change the windows user
- Change the screen resolution
- Change the chrome size

And google still detects it’s me
How is possible that?

It should be because the explorer has something.

I really appreciate your help, thank you guys

Comment: [`navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) tells everything about you.

Comment: It is called [browser fingerprinting](https://www.google.com/search?q=browser+fingerprinting&oq=browser+fingerprinting)

Comment: It is great to trick something big as google. Read about fraud detection and you will find it. And google is the boss for everything, I have tried to trick trip advisor and did not make it.... For e.g. they get your Ip, user, OS, Browser version,..everything that you can imagine. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

### Cookie

Your browser might have been sending cookie set by google. You can [check your cookies in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/244062/how-do-i-view-add-or-edit-cookies-in-google-chrome).

### Browser Fingerprinting

Server can identify you by combination of various attributes like User Agent, Accept, Content Encoding, list of plugins, platform, and etc...
[Further readings](https://hub.packtpub.com/all-about-browser-fingerprinting-the-privacy-nightmare-that-keeps-web-developers-awake-at-night/) on Browser Fingerprinting here.